# "Planned on system": meaning (G.M. Trevelyan, A Short History of England)

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> Their method of conquest was to make military roads, planned on system for the whole island, and to plant along them forts garrisoned by the regular troops.

I can't manage to explain this construction from the fundamental definitions of "on" in the [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/on_1?q=on).

The SOED (*Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*) does not reveal any satisfactory solution.

There is the following definition, but "system" is not a word connoting action.

> (SOED) **II**  Of time or action implying time **7** On the occasion (of an action); immediately after (and because of or in reaction to), as a result of.
> S. FORESTER The captain came instantly on hearing your summons.
> F. TUOHY Roland's first decision on leaving .. was entirely conventional.

(Their method of conquest was to make military roads, planned **as a result of (a)** system for the whole island, and to plant along them forts garrisoned by the regular troops.

I would say that "on" could mean "as part of (a)", but this is a wild guess supported by nothing other than common sense, so an entirely different idea might be involved.

Comment: Other instances of “planned on system”: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22planned%20on%20system%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1977,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: Trevalyn's wording is awkward. "Their method of conquest was to make military roads, *systematically planned* for the whole island, and to plant along them forts garrisoned by the regular troops," makes more sense.

Comment: What @DJohnson said (***on system*** here is just a really awkward alternative to ***according to a system, systematically***.

Comment: ...but I see that no less a writer than [Samuel Taylor Coleridge](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22correspondent+cultivation+of+moral+science%22) penned this: *Woe be to us if we cultivate the science of rich living without a correspondent cultivation of moral science, **carried out on system** and interwoven into our economical polity!* But that was back in 1850; he probably wouldn't have written that if he'd been born a century later.

Comment: All of this (Google, Coleridge) might have one thinking that they are possibly dealing with a fixed expression, then, rather than an awkward formulation.

Comment: @DJohnson If you have an answer, please post it as an answer rather than a comment, so that the question can be resolved.

Comment: Yes, it's an adverbial phrase that means something like "strategically".

Comment: @alphabet  You mean that little one sentence toss away comment deserves elevation to a response?

Comment: @DJohnson It answers the question, does it not?

Comment: @alphabet Ha! Whoomp, there it is.

Comment: @Graffito "Planned", it seems to me, is a past participle used as an adjective, and so it postmodifies "road"; as a consequence we'd have "…military roads, forecasted defence system"; first, roads can be part of a system of defence but not be a defense systtem in themselves, and then I can't make out what "forecasted roads" would mean.  It seems that your interpretation is "system that has been planned on"; I can't see that clearly. // It seems likely now that "on system" has a meaning of its own (Coleridge and one of the Brontës used it); it is left to ascertain what the meaning is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On system** = systematically:

The OED has the entry for "**System**" which is preceded by a preposition to give an adjunct:

> **System (n.) II.15.**
>
> **As a mass noun. Orderly arrangement or method; systematic form or order.**
>
> 1699 *Aristotle is more noted for his order, in bringing Morality into
> Systeme,..and distinguishing vertues into their several kinds, which
> had not been handled Systematically before.* T. Baker, Reflections
> upon Learning vi. 68
>
> 1822 *The work of the house is performed as if by magic, but it is the
> magic of system.* W. Irving, Bracebridge Hall iii. 28
>
> 1876 *Macaulay, even during his hours of leisure, began to read **on system**.* G. O. Trevelyan, Life & Letters of Macaulay vol. II. xv. 474
>
> 1992 *A cognition that is produced methodically, but without system,
> is rhapsodic.* J. M. Young, translation of I. Kant, Lect. on Logic 287

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple additional attestations where the meaning seems to shade more towards "strategically" or  "purposefully".

> It is good for women, especially, to be endowed with a soft blindness; to have mild, dim eyes, that never penetrate below the surface of things—that take all for what it seems. Thousands, knowing this, keep their eyelids drooped **on system**; but the most downcast glance has its loophole, through which it can, on occasion, take its sentinel-survey of life.

Brontë , Charlotte. Shirley, A Tale Novel by Charlotte Brontë Annotated (p. 353). Kindle Edition.

> In all this Miss Keeldar partly yielded to her disposition; but a remark she made a year afterwards proved that she partly also acted **on system**. "Louis," she said, "would never have learned to rule if she had not ceased to govern. The incapacity of the sovereign had developed the powers of the premier."

Brontë , Charlotte. Shirley, A Tale Novel by Charlotte Brontë Annotated (p. 800). Kindle Edition.

And there's an 1868 article from  *The Spectator* describing a murder:

> ... murder of a cool, deliberate kind, murder planned **on system** ...

cited in *Victorian Crime, Madness and Sensation*, Andrew Maunder and Grace Moore, editors. 2004

Answer (score 1):

Trevalyn's wording is awkward.

His wording can be improved by writing, "Their method of conquest was to make military roads, *systematically planned* for the whole island, and to plant along them forts garrisoned by the regular troops."